# CSS Formatting Issues?

Tags: html, css, formatting

I am working on an a project for my online radio station, and that is the station's website. I worked really hard on it, made it look beautiful, and was really proud. For now, I'm hosting it at a free hosting/subdomain service for now. It's really causing me grief because the format works with my computer, but when I go to the URL (in the same browser) on a different computer, everything's fine except for the CSS (fonts, wrappers, etc...). The formatting of the site is way off.

This is my first time actually uploading a site I've created to the web, so I'm pretty new at this. Is there something I'm missing, or?

The full link to my website is http://thexradioonline.host56.com and some of the CSS is below. I'm willing to try anything to get this to work.

```
#body{
margin-top:0px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-bottom:0px;
background-color:#999999;
}

#wrapper{
height:auto;
width:1000px;
float:center;
padding-left:200px;
}
```

I would provide more code, but all I know is it's a formatting issue. Again, I've never done this before, so if someone knows the problem, that would be great.

Comment: You need to try and list a specific issue/s. What is not right with the fonts? what is not right with the wrappers? etc

Comment: Right. We don't know what it looks like for you on the two computers, so error descriptions like "way off" are far too vague. Be specific! Maybe you could post some screen shots of the differences?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your question is why is your font `font-family:neou;` not working for every one, this is because you are using a none standard font, that i assume you have installed on your pc but the other machines do not.

You can fix your problem in 3 different ways. The first approach would be to change the font you are using to one that everyone will have, [CSS font stack](http://cssfontstack.com/) should help here. A second approach would be to choose a font from a library, like [Google font](https://www.google.com/fonts) that allows you to include a font via a `<link/>` attribute or JavaScript or `@import` in your CSS. A third approach would be to upload all the files related to your font onto your server and use `@font-face` to add it to your CSS, such as :

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'neou';
  src: url('neou.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('neou.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('neou.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('neou.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('neou.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

[reference](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/)